# How to get value from @Html.CheckBoxFor()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Can you tell me how to get the value of `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.cb, new { value = "myvalue" })` from controller?

I had tried with GET method, and the result in url was `?cb=myvalue&&cb=true`

So, I wrote an action to get the value but it said that I cannot convert boolean to string.

```
public ActionResult GetValues(string cb)
{
   ViewBag.Value = cb;
   return View();
}
```

Can you tell me how to do that? Thanks!

Comment: Seems you are new to MVC , Check my answer and let me know if you requires any further assistance

Comment: @MikeDebela I create a bool variable in model but i want to use a string to store the value. `public bool cb { get; set; }`

Comment: @Kevin your welcome , don's miss to mark as answer so other can also get benefit

Comment: Then you can do `string value = cb ? "myvalue" : "anothervalue"` in your controller just `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.cb)` will be enough

Comment: `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` is for binding to a boolean property which has only 2 possible states - `true` or `false`. Why on earth are you trying to set the value to something else? If you want to post back a a `string`, then create the html for checkbox manually so it does not include the hidden input

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes. I agree. CheckBoxFor needs a boolean variable to validate. But, you can add another value like a string in the content. Like this: `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.cb, new { value = "myvalue" })` So, the `cb` is a boolean variable, and the `value` is a string. And I want to get the value of `value = "myvalue"`, not `true` or `false`

Comment: Then you need to manually generate the html so it does not pass back the value of the hidden input (`false`) as well (which is why you currently get `?cb=myvalue&&cb=false` - `<input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="myvalue" />`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
 public ActionResult GetValues([Bind(Include = "cb")] yourmodelName yourmodelobject)
        {
            ViewBag.Value = yourmodelobject.cb
           return View();
        }
```